# How to remove space between object and method calls in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, code-cleanup

I am planning for code cleanup , lot of places I found code like below which is not easily readable.

[image]

To make it readable removing spaces between object and method call like as below

[image]

Is there any plugin or eclipse feature available to remove this kind of space automatically from code.

Comment: There is no space. It's just a linebreak at the maximum line length configured in your editor.

Comment: Eclipse has a built-in code formatter for exactly that purpose. There are numerous settings and you have to experiment a little to get to the desired code formatting rules.

Comment: Just modify the "Line Wrapping" in the Formatter and go for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you highlight the code the press `Ctrl+Shift+F`, Eclipse will auto format the code highlighted as per the rules in `Window | Preferences | Java | Code Style | Formatter` so just set those rules as per your desire then auto format.

Specifically, in your case just `Edit` the `Active Profile` and adjust the settings on the `Line Wrapping` tab.

*Valid as of Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2*

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+A(Select All) and Ctrl+Shift+F(Format) to format your entire file or select the area where you want to format and press Ctrl+Shift+F.